# Remove a specific digit from a variable in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge a few data sets using a unique identifier (FIPS code). One of the data sets won't merge, and I believe it's because it contains an extra 0 in the FIPS code. All the FIPS codes in the other data sets contain 7 total digits, but in the problematic one, there are 8 digits.

For example, this is what the variable looks like in the properly merging data frames:

```
0100180
0100185
0100210
0100240
0100270
0604950
0605010
0610770
0611040
```

But the variable in the problematic data frame contains an extra digit (always a zero, from what I can tell):

```
01000180
01000185
01000210
01000240
01000270
06004950
06005010
06010770
06011040
```

Is there a way I can remove just this 0 found in the 3rd digit spot? I've searched the forums but can't find a post that speaks to this, or if it does, it's beyond my ability.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$var <- gsub("^(..).", "\\1", df$var)
```

Comment: From what I can tell so far, this worked! Brilliant!! I'm truly thankful.